# How to check if 2 strings match with one containing '*' that can replace all char or string?

Tags: c, string-matching

I am looking for hints to help me come up with the solution I tried many algorithms and none of them seems to work over all cases. I know there is a **recursive solution building a function of just a few lines** but I can't come up with it.

Here are the instructions:

> The purpose of this function is to find out whether two strings match.
>
> - s1 and s2 are considered to match when s1 and s2 are identical.
> - If s2 contains a star (`’*’`), we can replace this star by any characters string (even empty) to make s1 and s2 identical.
> - s2 may hold as many stars as you’d like.
> - For example, `"main.c"` and `"*.c"` match because it is possible to replace `’*’` by the string `"main"` to render those two strings identical.
> - Here’s how it should be prototyped :
>     int match(char *s1, char *s2);
> - It must return 1 if s1 and s2 match, or 0 if they don’t.

My function will be in C.

The hard cases are:

```
s1 = "abcde" & s2 = "a*e*d"
s1 = "abcdecde" & s2 = "a*e"
```

Comment: Let's say you have strings s1 and s2. You need to think recursively. You need to have 2 indices keeping the current position on each string. When you encounter a star on s2 for instance, you need to go s1 and think that for each character, you can either include it as part of the star matching, or not.

Comment: When copy+pasting a homework problem here, please always convert it to Markdown. That means replacing item "circle" characters with asterisks, so that a proper list is rendered. It also means surrounding asterisks you want to show with backticks, so that the essential material is visible. As you would have seen, your asterisks disappeared in your text (and turned on italics that you did not intend). Above all, always proof-read!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a glob matcher that yours truly won the 2001 IOCCC with:

```
main(int c,char**v){return!m(v[1],v[2]);}
m(char*s,char*t){return*t-42?*s?63==*t|*s==*t&&m(s+1,t+1):!*t:m(s,t+1)||*s&&m(s+1,t);}
```

In addition to `*` it also understands `?` for *exactly one character*. Stripping `?` support should be a fun exercise :-) It might be helpful to read the [hints](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html#2001_schweikh).